# ホームページで入力された情報をスプレッドシートに保存する方法

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

ホームページから名前やメールアドレスの入力をしたときに、それらを保存する方法がわからないので知りたい。
javascriptは次のようなコードです。

調べたことについては
googleのApps Scriptという機能があること
JSONの形式でデータを送れること
などです。

現在のjavascriptのコードです。

```
(() => {
    const submitAccount = () => {
        window.setAccount('name', document.getElementById('accountName').value)
        window.setAccount('email', document.getElementById('accountEmail').value)
        window.setAccount('zip', document.getElementById('accountZip').value)
        window.setAccount('address', document.getElementById('accountAddress').value)
        window.setAccount('bankName', document.getElementById('accountBankName').value)
        window.setAccount('bankStore', document.getElementById('accountBankStore').value)
        window.setAccount('bankType1', document.getElementById('accountBankType1').checked)
        window.setAccount('bankType2', document.getElementById('accountBankType2').checked)
        window.setAccount('bankNumber', document.getElementById('accountBankNumber').value)
        window.setAccount('userName', document.getElementById('accountUserName').value)

        document.getElementById('accountSuccess').style.display = 'flex'
        document.getElementById('accountFailure').style.display = 'none'
    }

    const fetchAccount = () => {
        const account = window.getAccount()

        document.getElementById('accountName').value = account['name'] ?? ''
        document.getElementById('accountEmail').value = account['email'] ?? ''
        document.getElementById('accountZip').value = account['zip'] ?? ''
        document.getElementById('accountAddress').value = account['address'] ?? ''
        document.getElementById('accountBankName').value = account['bankName'] ?? ''
        document.getElementById('accountBankStore').value = account['bankStore'] ?? ''
        document.getElementById('accountBankType1').checked = account['bankType1'] ?? false
        document.getElementById('accountBankType2').checked = account['bankType2'] ?? false
        document.getElementById('accountBankNumber').value = account['bankNumber'] ?? ''
        document.getElementById('accountUserName').value = account['userName'] ?? ''
    }

    document.getElementById('accountSubmit').addEventListener('click', submitAccount)
    fetchAccount()
})()
```

これらを表の形式で書き出したいと思います。

javascriptについては知識があまりないです。
コードと解説とともに教えていただけると大変ありがたいです。

Comment: Google Apps Script を使ってスプレッドシートにデータを保存するのは[ウェブアプリ  |  Apps Script  |  Google for Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=ja) を起動して `doPost` でJSONで受け取るだけですが、何が分かっていないのかを明示できると解答しやすそうです。